# Proper behaviour of a linux daemon

Tags: linux, daemon, systems-programming

What behaviours define a well written Linux daemon? I read about the double fork, closing standard file descriptors, and so on, but I wonder if someone experienced in writing these things could give me the low down.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to just call the [daemon()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) function. It takes care of all of that for you.